# Please help to write a tcp udp scanner program in python

Tags: python-3.x

write a program in Python that allows you to discover the IP of the network in which your machine is located, in
a certain interface, indicated by the user when executing the program (with the -i option).

Once you have found the IPs, you must show the ports you have open, both for TCP and UDP, and next to the port, you must indicate
the service banner, using the Banner Grabbing technique.

In addition, the result must be encoded in JSON format and sent via a POST request to the url:
http://127.0.0.1/example/fake_url.php

Note that it is a false URL, and that it will not respond to the request. This situation must be controlled correctly, to avoid
program interruption

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that shows what you've tried so far, and explain why it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to SO! When you place a question try to add a minimum content: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try, research and where are you stuck. SO is not a free coding service. You should show some effort.

Comment: >>> import psutil
>>> addrs = psutil.net_if_addrs()
>>> print(addrs.keys())
dict_keys(['Ethernet', 'VirtualBox Host-Only Network', 'Conexión de área local* 1', 'Conexión de área local* 2', 'Ethernet 2', 'Wi-Fi', 'Conexión de red Bluetooth', 'Loopback Pseudo-Interface 1'])